# Display Top Bar for Users from Specific Link?

Tags: wordpress, banner

I'm looking to have my frontpage display a specific bar to welcome users who are arriving from a specific link (somewhere I am advertising).

So you'll see the homepage, when visiting from www.example.com/example1
but they'll be an additional banner at the top of the page saying welcome etc.

Using wordpress, www.naturettl.com

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [URL Params plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/url-params/) is probably the easiest way to accomplish this.  You can utilize shortcodes (as they've defined in the plugin) inside your content to look for specific URL parameters.

So instead of www.example.com/example1 you would have your advertiser use a link such as www.example.com/?campaign=123 (where "campaign" is any variable name you wish and "123" is the specific advertising campaign).

Comment: My header does not support shortcodes, and I don't think achieves exactly what I'm looking for. I'd like a full width colour banner with text on at the top, that can be closed using an X button or something. I know a plugin for the banner, but not sure how to make it specific to a certain link.